# iterating through list - splitting strings

Tags: python, list, split

I have a list of `drawingnumbers`, I am attempting to split these strings and then append to a number of lists.

I am hoping to end up with a number of lists, which contains each relevant piece of the original string.

At the minute my definition is iterating through the list, but overwriting the variables, not appending them. So I have a single entry for each variable and these correspond to the final entry of the list.

Could anybody please help?

```
# drawingnumber split 

 drawingnumber = ["AAA601-XXX-A-L00-1028-DR-GA-200-001",
 "AAA601-XXX-A-L10-1028-DR-GA-200-001",
 "AAA601-XXX-A-L00-1029-DR-GA-200-001",
 "AAA601-XXX-A-L00-1029-DR-GA-200-XXX"]

 building = []  
 buildinglist = []  
 originator = []  
 discipline = []  
 level = []  
 scope = []  
 drawingtype = []  
 drawingsubtype = []  
 numbera = []  
 numberb = []

 for i in drawingnumber:  
    building, originator, discipline, level, scope, \
    drawingtype,drawingsubtype, numbera, numberb = i.split("-")

 print("building:", building)  
 print("originator: ", originator)  
 print("discipline: ", discipline)  
 print("level: ", level)  
 print("scope: ", scope)  
 print("drawingtype: ", drawingtype)  
 print("drawingsubtype", drawingsubtype)  
 print("drawingident", numbera, "-", numberb)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `zip` after splitting each element in the list to transpose your lists as:

```
zip(*[i.split("-") for i in drawingnumber])
```

And assign them to lists names:

```
building, originator, discipline, level, scope, \
drawingtype, drawingsubtype, numbera, numberb = zip(*[i.split("-") for i in drawingnumber])
```

Example output:

```
building
# ('AAA601', 'AAA601', 'AAA601', 'AAA601')

originator
# ('XXX', 'XXX', 'XXX', 'XXX')

numberb
# ('001', '001', '001', 'XXX')
```

Comment: @Jup: If the answer helped out, consider upvoting/accepting it (the green tick on the left).

Answer (score 0):

Just change

```
 for i in drawingnumber:  
    building, originator, discipline, level, scope,  drawingtype,drawingsubtype, numbera, numberb = i.split("-")
```

to:

```
 for i in drawingnumber:  
    building_, originator_, discipline_, level_, scope_,  drawingtype_,drawingsubtype_, numbera_, numberb_ = i.split("-")
    building.append(building_)
    originator.append(originator_)
    ...etc...
```

splitted valeus redefine your variables each time what you want to do here is basically append those to lists you created, also pick plural names for list like: buildings and append singular variables to them

Answer (score 0):

```
drawingnumber = ["AAA601-XX1-A-L00-1028-DR-GA-200-001",
 "AAA602-XX2-A-L10-1028-DR-GA-200-001",
 "AAA603-XX3-A-L00-1029-DR-GA-200-001",
 "AAA604-XX4-A-L00-1029-DR-GA-200-XXX"]

building = []  
buildinglist = []  
originator = []  
discipline = []  
level = []  
scope = []  
drawingtype = []  
drawingsubtype = []  
numbera = []  
numberb = []

for i in drawingnumber:
    j = i.split('-')
    building.append(j[0])
    buildinglist.append(j[1])


for i in range(len(drawingnumber)):
    print("building:", building[i])
    print("buildinglist:", buildinglist[i])
```